# SAPUI5 - Mobile app paging, alternatives to paginator

Tags: pagination, sapui5

I'm investing a survey / questionnaire app in SAPUI5...

As it's mainly to be used on a mobile device, and the questionnaires will consist of many questions,  what are the best SAPUI5 components to use for paging through the questions?

Paginator is ugly and will be deprecated soon, so I'm looking for alternative suggestions.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about NavContainer. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.NavContainer/preview

It is very good fit for your use case , and it has good user experience in mobile devices. You can define your own Back and Next button in the footer to navigate between different questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one thing though. The questions will be retrieved from one object... How would you split them between the pages?  Say for 20 questions,  example 4 questions per page over 5 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered by Allen, so this is an alternavtive suggestion.

Assuming  that your model will be something like:

```
{
    "Questions": [{
        "QuestionID": "0001",
        "QuestionText":"What is a Blah?"
        "Options": [{
            "OptionA":"Blah",
            "OptionB":"BlahBlah",
            "OptionC":"BlahBlahBlah",
            "OptionD":"None Of the Above Blahs"
        }]
        },{
        "QuestionID": "0002",
        "QuestionText":"To Blah or not to Blah?"
        "Options": [{
            "OptionA":"Yes",
            "OptionB":"No",
            "OptionC":"Blah",
            "OptionD":"Blah ha ha ha"
        }]
    }]
}
```

You can also accomplish the same effect without a NavContainer and a Single View. The View will be bound to the above model. The View / Page might have two buttons for the "next" and "previous" functionality. On click of each button you can manipulate the BindingContext that is bound to the view so that the Context changes and not the view. To set a new BindingContext, you can track which question is currently displayed on the screen and use the .bindElement function to set the Path of the next / previous element to be displayed.

- Pros: Only one View and Controller
- Cons: Need to manage the context and paths, Also means that the binding is little more complex and you might need factory functions based on whether the number of answers can vary between 2 (True / False questions) to 4 (MCP as in the above example)

Helpful link for Element Binding: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.tutorial.databinding.13/preview

Comment: That's actually really helpful. It still doesn't 100% answer my question. E.g how do I setup (for example) 4 questions per page out of a model of 20 questions. (5 pages).....

Comment: In the above example the Binding context brings back a single 'product', how do I display more than one. (In my case it'll be questons not products)

Comment: So your model will contain a root node called (say) "Questions".That would be a collection of other nodes (like in the example above). In SAPUI5, elements at specific locations in a model can be located using their relevant path. Eg. for the first (0th) question ID we use Questions/0/QuestionID. Or for the second Question Text we use Questions/1/QuestionText. In such fashion, if your plan is to show 4 questions on a single page, then create 4 panels or groups of controls. Place them in any suitable layout (GridLayout) on the view.

Comment: In the onBeforeShow method of the view, you will need to manipulate path of which path to bind to which group. Eg. the first group should be bound to Questions/0/, the second Questions/1/, and so on. When "Next" or "Previous" is called, you will be calling an event handler that will manipulate the value of /x/ in the path and then call bindElement on each group. NOTE: I still using a single question at a time simply because on mobile devices or tablets having 4 questions may cause scrolling. Plus using a single question at a time will be much simpler and maintainable code. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you help on this. I'd like to use binding path/context to create a new survey create app, but just need some examples of manipulating the binding to create a new path for example, I've created a new question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115723/how-do-i-use-binding-path-context-to-build-multi-page-app-using-a-single-view)