# How do I use Binding path/context to build (multi-page app) using a single view / controller?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I'm building a create survey / questionnaire app, where each question has the exact same format bound to a model.

Is it possible to do this with one controller + view and simply manipulate the binding context/path?

I've created a single view for this in SAP WEB IDE. When I go click on the "Add New question" button, (to display the input for Question 2) how exactly do I setup the new binding path/context to accept data for it?

[image]

Comment: Controller and view have nothing to do with a binding context. Perhaps sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.createEntry( sPath, mParameters) returning a new context is what you are looking for?

Comment: Not sure. I will have a "question" view model in the controller which will include an array of questions (array 0 = question 1, array 1 = question 2 etc).. Obviously the first page will be assigned to the first array element, but when I click on "New question" how do create a new array element for question 2 and access it in the view?

Comment: It is possible, you could set the binding context of the form to a single entity every time you click on Add New question

Comment: That's what I'm after thank you. But could you give an example ?